# Navbar color in a Bootsrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I just downloaded a template from [startbootstrap.com](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/) and I'm having troubles finding the navbar property in the CSS that changes the color when you are viewing the section of the page. Here is the code of the CSS dowloaded from the site:

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Freelancer Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

p.small {
    font-size: 16px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a.active {
    outline: 0;
    color: #18bc9c;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

hr.star-light,
hr.star-primary {
    margin: 25px auto 30px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 250px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

hr.star-light:after,
hr.star-primary:after {
    content: "\f005";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.8em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 2em;
}

hr.star-light {
    border-color: #fff;
}

hr.star-light:after {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #18bc9c;
}

hr.star-primary {
    border-color: #2c3e50;
}

hr.star-primary:after {
    color: #2c3e50;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.img-centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #18bc9c;
}

header .container {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

header img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

header .intro-text .name {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

header .intro-text .skills {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header .container {
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    header .intro-text .name {
        font-size: 4.75em;
    }

    header .intro-text .skills {
        font-size: 1.75em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        padding: 25px 0;
        -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
        -moz-transition: padding .3s;
        transition: padding .3s;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

.navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-default,
.navbar-inverse {
    border: 0;
}

section {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

section h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}

section.success {
    color: #fff;
    background: #18bc9c;
}

section.success a,
section.success a:hover,
section.success a:focus,
section.success a:active,
section.success a.active {
    outline: 0;
    color: #2c3e50;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    section {
        padding: 75px 0;
    }

    section.first {
        padding-top: 75px;
    }
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item {
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(24,188,156,.9);
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content i {
    margin-top: -12px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h3,
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio * {
    z-index: 2;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    #portfolio .portfolio-item {
        margin: 0 0 30px;
    }
}

.btn-outline {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline:active,
.btn-outline.active {
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    color: #18bc9c;
    background: #fff;
}

.floating-label-form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.floating-label-form-group input,
.floating-label-form-group textarea {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: 0 0;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    resize: none;
}

.floating-label-form-group label {
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.764705882em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;
}

.floating-label-form-group::not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 14px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
    color: #18bc9c;
}

form .row:first-child .floating-label-form-group {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

footer {
    color: #fff;
}

footer h3 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

footer .footer-above {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

footer .footer-col {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

footer .footer-below {
    padding: 25px 0;
    background-color: #233140;
}

.btn-social {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
    outline: 0;
}

.scroll-top {
    z-index: 1049;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2%;
    bottom: 2%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.scroll-top .btn {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.scroll-top .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content {
    padding: 100px 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content .item-details {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
    opacity: .3;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
    z-index: 1051;
    width: 1px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
    z-index: 1052;
    width: 1px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[Here](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/) you can find the live preview of the template I just downloaded.

I have searched every part of the code but I can't find the part that will change that color. If someone could help me I will appreciate it a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Navbar background color? Blue?

Comment: When you are in portfolio section (for example) a darker rectangle appear around the navbar section, that one is the one I want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps: I pulled it from another thread.

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #000;  /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >   
 a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
background-color: #030033;
}

  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #0f006f;
    border-color: #030033;
}

  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
   .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #262626;
   text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #66CCFF;  /*change color of links in drop down here*/
   }

 .nav > li > a:hover,
 .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: silver; /*Change rollover cell color here*/
  }


  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: white; /*Change active text color here*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

.navbar-default is the class for the entire nav bar itself, if you want the active button a different color that would be the .page-scroll.active class

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add these to the freelancer.css See example when scrolling or add the active class to a `nav li`.

```
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```js
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Freelancer Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

// Floating label headings for the contact form
$(function() {
  $("body").on("input propertychange", ".floating-label-form-group", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("floating-label-form-group-with-value", !!$(e.target).val());
  }).on("focus", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
    $(this).addClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
  }).on("blur", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
  });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

```css
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    padding: 25px 0;
    -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
    -moz-transition: padding .3s;
    transition: padding .3s;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
.navbar {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.navbar-default,
.navbar-inverse {
  border: 0;
}
/***Link Background and Color Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body id="page-top" class="index">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>

      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="hidden">
            <a href="#page-top"></a>

          </li>
          <li class="active"> <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

          </li>
          <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#about">About</a>

          </li>
          <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/profile.png" alt="">
          <div class="intro-text"> <span class="name">Start Bootstrap</span>

            <hr class="star-light"> <span class="skills">Web Developer - Graphic Artist - User Experience Designer</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
  <section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>Portfolio</h2>

          <hr class="star-primary">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/cake.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/circus.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/game.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/safe.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="caption">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/portfolio/submarine.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- About Section -->
  <section class="success" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>About</h2>

          <hr class="star-light">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
          <p>Freelancer is a free bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap. The download includes the complete source files including HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well as optional LESS stylesheets for easy customization.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p>Whether you're a student looking to showcase your work, a professional looking to attract clients, or a graphic artist looking to share your projects, this template is the perfect starting point!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
            <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Theme
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>Contact Me</h2>

          <hr class="star-primary">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
          <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
          <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="row control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row control-group">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="text-center">
    <div class="footer-above">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
            <h3>Location</h3>

            <p>3481 Melrose Place
              <br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
            <h3>Around the Web</h3>

            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li> <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus"></i></a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a>

              </li>
              <li> <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dribbble"></i></a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
            <h3>About Freelancer</h3>

            <p>Freelance is a free to use, open source Bootstrap theme created by <a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-below">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Scroll to Top Button (Only visible on small and extra-small screen sizes) -->
  <div class="scroll-top page-scroll visible-xs visible-sm">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </a>

  </div>
  <!-- Portfolio Modals -->
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/cake.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/circus.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/game.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/safe.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2>Project Title</h2>

              <hr class="star-primary">
              <img src="img/portfolio/submarine.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
              <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase
                the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                <li>Client: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Date: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
                <li>Service: <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>

                </li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbar-default {
background-color: green; //Change color of nav background
border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: black; //Change color of nav links
}
```

Edit: I think this is the one

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
background-color: red; //Change color around link
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the next rule is responsible for active link in navbar (based on your live preview):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1a242f;
}
```

In order to inspect your css, but not to find the desired rule by randomly made changes use browser page inspector (now its almost always built-in).

Answer (score 0):

1. navbar-default is class for the entire nav bar
2. if you want the active button a different color that would be the .page-scroll.active class

   .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >
    a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
   color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
   background-color: #030033;
   }

   .navbar-default {
       background-color: #0f006f;
       border-color: #030033;
   }

   .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
      .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
       color: #262626;
      text-decoration: none;
     background-color: #66CCFF;  /*change color of links in drop down here*/
      }

   .nav > li > a:hover,
    .nav > li > a:focus {
       text-decoration: none;
       background-color: silver; /*Change rollover cell color here*/
     }